# Encrypt Blazor Server SignalR traffic

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, signalr

is it possible to encrypt the traffic for SignalR / Blazor Server Applications? When I go into Developer mode I can see the Websocket Stream and there you can see some values sometimes, so I asked myself if it would be possible to encrypt the traffic?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69861378/how-to-encrypt-values-sent-in-dispatchbrowserevent-in-blazor-server-side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"If your SignalR application transmits sensitive information between the client and server, use SSL for the transport." from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/security/introduction-to-security). Encryption is handled by the transport layer. What you see in the browser is already

1. decrypted (if using SSL)
2. in the application layer (browser).

In simple terms: there is no need for extra encryption.